# $\phi: \mathbb{R}[X] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a homomorphism such that: $\phi(X) = 1 + i$. What is $\ker \phi$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism, polynomial-rings

$\phi: \mathbb{R}[X] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a homomorphism such that: $\phi(X) = 1 + i$.
What is $\ker \phi$?

In my thinking $\ker \phi = \{0\}$ because there is no way to add or multiply $1 + i$ in such way that it would be equal to $0$. Am I right?

Comment: Oh, so there must be an error in the exercise. Thank you.

Comment: @Surb Why is $\phi(0) \ne 0$?

Comment: There is no error in the exercise, this morphism is well-defined (but it should be required to be an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra morphism, not just a ring morphism).

Comment: @CaptainLama and then what would be the kernel?

Comment: $\phi$ _is_ an homomorphism: every ${\mathbb R}$-algebra homomorphism from ${\mathbb R}[X]$ to ${\mathbb C}$ is uniquely defined by giving its value on $X$. So, $\phi$ here maps an $f \in {\mathbb R}[X]$ to $f(1 + i)$. So, the question is: what polynomials over ${\mathbb R}$ evaluate to $0$ at $1 + i$?

Comment: @blackkay1 now, what do you conclude from $\phi(X^2-2X)=-2?$

Comment: Do you know what a minimal polynomial is? The kernel is the ideal generated by the minimal polynomial of $1+i$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @blackkay1, indeed, but what does it learn about which polynomial is in the kernel?

Comment: The answer is: all the polynomials generated by $x^2 -2x + 2$. To be exact in writing: $<x^2 -2x + 2>$Am I right? I think I get it now.

Comment: @CaptainLama actually you don't have to assume that $\phi$ has been uniquely specified. It is any $\phi$ taking $X \to 1+i$ and for all polynomials you leave their coefficients as $\phi (a_i)$. Then use what you know about $\phi$ on the integers.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_jx^j$ then $\phi(p(x))=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j\phi(x)^j=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j(1+i)^j$, so $p(x)\in\ker(\phi)$ iff $1+i$ is a root of $p(x)$. But, since we are working with real polynomials, a complex number is a root of a polynomial iff its conjugate is also a root, so $1+i$ and $1-i$ are roots of $p(x)$. Then $p(x)\in\ker(\phi)$ iff $p(x)=q(x)(x-1-i)(x-1+i)=q(x)(x^2-2x+2)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$ iff $p(x)$ is in the ideal generated by $x^2-2x+2$. This proves that $\ker(\phi)=\langle x^2-2x+2\rangle$.

This is the most elementary solution one can get, but as suggested in the comments this is connected with the minimal polynomial. In general, if $\phi(x)=z\in\mathbb{C}$  the kernel will be the ideal generated by the minimal polynomial of $z$.